# empty body on resource.$save

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

So I've tried the suggestions from

- [AngularJS POSTs empty requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228530/angularjs-posts-empty-requests)
- [AngularJS $resource RESTful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269882/angularjs-resource-restful-example)
- [Send Request Body on $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203646/send-request-body-on-resource)

But I'm still getting an empty req.body

I can do a get just fine and even pass an id for the get. But I can't seem to POST and transfer the data to the server.

Controller:

```
.controller("createEventController", ["$scope", 'CreateEventService', '$location', function($scope, CreateEventService, $location){
    $scope.event = {};

    $scope.submitEvent = function(){
        console.log($scope.event);
        var events = new CreateEventService($scope.event);

        console.log(events);

        events.save(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
}])
```

Service

```
factory('CreateEventService', function($resource){      
   return $resource('api/createEvent');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using express 4.1.2, despite it fussing about bodyParser() being deprecated, having

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));
```

was for some reason, giving me an empty body. For whatever reason, not having *urlencoded* crashed my server before (old express version I think). Just change it back to (using express 4.1.2)

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

and fixed. I also removed the methodOverride() as that was causing my server to hang. If anyone knows a more *correct* approach, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Change `events.save(...)` to `events.$save(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bodyParser.json()`. The `$resource`, by default sends his requests with the header `"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` and without `bodyParser.json()` you're API is not able to deal with the request content.